# Making a chrome extension that replaces css and js elements

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I was wondering if there was a way to make a chrome extension that removes the js and css from the website wile it is loading and adds new script from a separate source. 
Kind of like this

'Old script' Gets replaced with 'new script 'Or  '' Gets replaced with ''

Vise versa with css

Sorry for my spelling I'm on my phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could take a look at [chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest), it fires when a request (such as script/stylesheet) is about to occur, and you're allowed to listen to it and cancel or redirect the requests to the url you want(script/stylesheet)

To achieve this,

1. Add `webRequest`, `webRequestBlocking` and host permissions for `permissions` field in `manifest.json`
2. Listen to `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` in background page.

   ```
   chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
       var srcUrl = details.url;
       var desUrl = YOUR_DESTINATION_URL;
       return { redirectUrl: desUrl};
   }, {
          types: ["stylesheet", "script"],
          urls: [YOUR MATCH PATTERN]
   }, ['blocking']);
   ```